# Limits on Python Lists?

Tags: python, list, numpy

I'm trying to assimilate a bunch of information into a usable array like this:

```
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in walk('E:/Machin Lerning/Econ/full_set'):
    ndata.extend(filenames)
for i in ndata:
    currfile = open('E:/Machin Lerning/Econ/full_set/' + str(i),'r')
    rawdata.append(currfile.read().splitlines())
    currfile.close()
rawdata = numpy.array(rawdata)

for order,file in enumerate(rawdata[:10]):
    for i in rawdata[order]:
        r = i.split(',')
        pdata.append(r)
    fdata.append(pdata)
    pdata = []
fdata = numpy.array(fdata)
plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(fdata[:,1,3])
```

EDIT: After printing ftada.shape when using the first 10 txt files

```
for order,file in enumerate(rawdata[:10]):
```

I see it is (10, 500, 7). But if i do not limit the size of this, and instead say

```
for order,file in enumerate(rawdata):
```

Then the fdata.shape is just (447,)
It seems like this happens whenever I increase the number of elements i look through in the rawdata array to above 13... It's not any specific location either - I changed it to

```
for order,file in enumerate(rawdata[11:24):
```

and that worked fine. aaaaahhh
In case it's useful: here's what a sample of what the text files looks like:

```
20080225,A,31.42,31.79,31.2,31.5,30575  
20080225,AA,36.64,38.95,36.48,38.85,225008  
20080225,AAPL,118.59,120.17,116.664,119.74,448847
```

Comment: That error usually means you're trying to do something like treat a two dimensional array as a three dimensional array. It's not related to the number of elements in the array. I suspect your problem has to do with how you've written the final line rather than anything else in the code.

Comment: Your code and the exception do not match (there is no `print` or `len`  in your code). It doesn't look like your executing the code you think you are. Perhaps there is a cache problem with Anaconda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `fdata` is an array, and the error is in `fdata[:,1,3]`.  That tries to index `fdata` with 3 indices, the slice, 1, and 3.  But if `fdata` is a 2d array, this will produce this error - `too many indices`.

When you get 'indexing' errors, figure out the `shape` of the offending array.  Don't just guess.  Add a debug statement `print(fdata.shape)`.

===================

Taking your file sample, as a list of lines:

```
In [822]: txt=b"""20080225,A,31.42,31.79,31.2,31.5,30575  
     ...: 20080225,AA,36.64,38.95,36.48,38.85,225008  
     ...: 20080225,AAPL,118.59,120.17,116.664,119.74,448847 """
In [823]: txt=txt.splitlines()

In [826]: fdata=[]
In [827]: pdata=[]
```

read one 'file':

```
In [828]: for i in txt:
     ...:     r=i.split(b',')
     ...:     pdata.append(r)
     ...: fdata.append(pdata)
     ...: 
     ...:     
In [829]: fdata
Out[829]: 
[[[b'20080225', b'A', b'31.42', b'31.79', b'31.2', b'31.5', b'30575  '],
  ....]]]
In [830]: np.array(fdata)
Out[830]: 
array([[[b'20080225', b'A', b'31.42', b'31.79', b'31.2', b'31.5',
         b'30575  '],
...]]], 
      dtype='|S8')
In [831]: _.shape
Out[831]: (1, 3, 7)
```

Read an 'identical file"

```
In [832]: for i in txt:
     ...:     r=i.split(b',')
     ...:     pdata.append(r)
     ...: fdata.append(pdata)

In [833]: len(fdata)
Out[833]: 2
In [834]: np.array(fdata).shape
Out[834]: (2, 6, 7)
In [835]: np.array(fdata).dtype
Out[835]: dtype('S8')
```

Note the dtype - a string of 8 characters.  Since on value per line is a string, it can't convert the whole thing to numbers.

Now read a slightly different 'file' (one less line, one less value)

```
In [836]: txt1=b"""20080225,A,31.42,31.79,31.2,31.5,30575  
     ...: 20080225,AA,36.64,38.95,36.48,38.85 """
In [837]: txt1=txt1.splitlines()
In [838]: for i in txt1:
     ...:     r=i.split(b',')
     ...:     pdata.append(r)
     ...: fdata.append(pdata)

In [839]: len(fdata)
Out[839]: 3
In [840]: np.array(fdata).shape
Out[840]: (3, 8)
In [841]: np.array(fdata).dtype
Out[841]: dtype('O')
```

Now lets add an 'empty' file - no rows so `pdata` is `[]`

```
In [842]: fdata.append([])
In [843]: np.array(fdata).shape
Out[843]: (4,)
In [844]: np.array(fdata).dtype
Out[844]: dtype('O')
```

Array shape and dtype have totally changed.  It can no longer create a uniform 3d array from the lines.

The shape after 10 files,  (10, 500, 7), means 10 files, 500 lines each, 7 columns each line.  But one file or more of the full 400 is different.  My last iteration suggests one is empty.

Comment: It seems that the shape of the array changes with the size? I don't understand this!

Comment: check the dtype as well. One or more of your files has a different layout.

Comment: It's not the total that matters; it's the file content.  See my simulated file read.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! But, here's the problem. Specifying a range of rawdata[0:26] returns a dimension of (26,). _But_ if i try it with rawdata[0,13] _or_ with [13,26] it returns the 3-d array: [13,500,7]. So how can it be a specific file?

Comment: I can't read your files!  How about a range that straddles `13`?  Or try `fdata.append(np.array(pdata))`.  That should make it easier to examine the shape and dtype produced by each file.  `np.stack(fdata, axis=0)` can be used to join all the arrays at the end.

Comment: I just decided to work around the weird limit of 13 at a time as per your suggestion. Thanks :D

Comment: I just noticed you collect the file lines in `rawdata`.  Why turn that into an array?  What's its shape and dtype?  What's the `len` of `rawdata` before the `array` statement?